# Django inline formset - get saved object

Tags: django, inline-formset

```
if formset.is_valid():
      formset.save()
```

Hello, how can i get saved inline formset object? In fact my formset hase no unique field.

Answer (score 1):

`formset.save()` will return a *list* of instances saved.

You could also go through each form within the formset and save them individually with:

```
for form in formset:
    myobject = form.save()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want access to the saved model instance, that can be done simply with:

```
if formset.is_valid():
    my_object = formset.save() # my_object now refers to the model instance.
```